# Convert String to Variable List

Tags: python, numpy

I have a string:

```
str='ABCDEFG'
```

I also have numpy arrays defined:

```
A=numpy.array([1,2,3])
B=numpy.array([2,3,4])
```

Now I want to be able to covert the string into a numpy array with the rows defined by these variables:

```
str=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],...]
```

These are very long strings and I would rather not loop through them with a find and replace type of operation.

Comment: So, what's the expected output for the sample case?

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension for the win:

```
In[18]: str='ABCDEFG'
In[19]: A=[1,2,3]
B=[2,3,4]
In[20]: [locals().get(x) for x in str if x in locals().keys()]
Out[20]: [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```

You should use `locals` or `globals` depending on your scope.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend the approach you're proposing. Managing variables and variable names is really the job of the programmer, not the program.

It seems like what you're trying to do would be accomplished easier with a DataFrame (i.e. table) object. Each row of the dataframe would have an identifier (a character within 'ABCDEFG' in your case).

I'd recommend checking out the pandas library: http://pandas.pydata.org/. It fits your use case well with minimal code:

```
import pandas as pd

rownames = list('AB')

dataframe = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]], index=rownames)

dataframe.loc['B'] # Returns [2, 3, 4] as a Series
```